# get String from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

How to get String from ArrayList if my code like

```
    ArrayList<String> PItoList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < AllPunchList.size(); i++) {
        PItoList.add(AllPunchList.get(i).toString());
    }
```

I want to split item in ArrayList one by one.

Comment: String from which ArrayList?

Comment: What does `AllPunchList` contains?

Comment: what doyou mean by split

Comment: Why you need split ? ArrayList data are separated by comma.You can directly access by index by help of an LOOP.

Comment: ArrayList<PunchList> AllPunchList = db.SearchPunchList(SS, DISC, DESC, RD, RB);

I want to split for get String. This String using to edit this item

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: It is unclear what, please explain what you want to do

Comment: I want to edit this data. So i get the value to send by intent
For edit, i use context menu

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:-

```
for(String eachString : PItoList){
    // eachString.split(regex); 
}
```

Traverse through each element in the `List` and do whatever you want to do in with each Element!

Comment: It can be either `PItoList` , or the `AllPunchList`! Nevertheless, the traversal is gonna be the same!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
ArrayList<String> PItoList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < AllPunchList.size(); i++) {
    PItoList.add((String)AllPunchList.get(i));
}
```

In the above example I have printed all elements in ArrayList. In this manner you can get all elements.

Then why you need split ?

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I will get String item one by one for edit the item.
I get value the item then send to form edit by intent. 
For edit, i use context menu.
I need example

Comment: Already the data in PItoList now. You can use those data any where.